# SASS mixin is included even though class doesn't exist

Tags: css, sass

I created two mixins which assign different values to the same variable that I want to use later in the header background url.

Depending on the html class variable `$image-name` should be different since I include different mixins but it always has a `"second-img"` value even though class `.second` doesn't exist in my html.

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.
Thanks!

```
@mixin first-image($image) {
    $image-name: $image !global;
}

@mixin second-image($image) {
    $image-name: $image !global;
}

html.first {
    @include first-image("first-img");
}

html.second {
    @include second-image("second-img");
}

header {
    background-image: url(../images/#{$image-name}-banner.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code when executed looks like this:

```
html.second {
    second-img {
        $image-name: second-img !global;
    }
}
```

Your mixing is pulling in the value of $image that you defined during the @include as they have the same variable names.

```
@mixin second-image($image) {
    $image-name: $image !global;
}
```

Change the variable name to something else and it won't display the same:

```
@mixin second-image($image) {
    $image-name: $thingy !global;
}
```